# How do I change blank OpenStreetMap tiles to be classified as water using PostGIS and GeoServer?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, geoserver

I'm following these two tutorials: (1) [LearnOSM](https://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm2pgsql/) and (2) [OSMGWC](https://github.com/fegyi001/osmgwc/blob/fa6130469a491446e75a33e778143eee5ebbfdaa/README.md). They cover OpenStreetMap, PostgreSQL + PostGIS, and GeoServer.

I've downloaded an extract of a state from [extract.bbbike.org](https://extract.bbbike.org/). I have all the layers configured together and the map looks perfect except for one thing: there's no surrounding ocean tiles. It's all white.

I'm thinking I could just replace all empty tiles with water tiles, and that would solve my problem. How can I do that? Or, if my idea sucks, what should I do instead?

[image: It's all white].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just downloading [water polygons](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/water-polygons) for the whole world and putting it at the bottom of my layer group. Worked out fine.